# What is the best Compose way to build preference screens without using a fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was unable to find any documentation on how to create preference screens in a pure Compose way without using a fragment.

Can anyone please suggest the best way to make a preference screen without using a fragment with an example? Or should we stick with the fragment way for that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

I have implemented my handmade settings screen for jetpack compose. This is a sample of my app using it. I know that this is isn't perfect but here is the link anyway if you want to try it:

[My repository](https://github.com/uragiristereo/Mejiboard/tree/main/app-alpha/src/main/java/com/github/uragiristereo/mejiboard/presentation/settings)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like using XML will be a cleaner solution.

Comment: @AtomHeartFather i recently refactored the settings screen, check the updated answer if you want to look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can compose it.  
A good example from the [Jetnews](https://github.com/Mohsents/android-jetpack-compose-demo/blob/7497ec8c10b098b3b1f3ad0e8279cbd5609e6b63/app/src/main/java/com/mohsents/androidjetpackcomposedemo/ui/interests/InterestsScreen.kt#L148) study app:

[image]

You can also use third-party libraries like [Compose-Settings](https://github.com/alorma/Compose-Settings) if prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a general `PreferenceItem` and then use components such as `Switch` or `Checkbox`.

```
@Composable
fun PreferenceItem(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    description: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    icon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {},
    action: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(min = LocalPreferenceSpacing.current.itemMinHeight)
            .clickable { onClick() }
            .padding(LocalPreferenceSpacing.current.itemPadding),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        if (icon != null) {
            IconContainer(icon = icon)
        }
        Details(
            title = title,
            description = description
        )
        if (action != null) {
            ActionContainer(action = action)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun SwitchPreference(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    checked: Boolean,
    onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    description: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    icon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    PreferenceItem(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = title,
        description = description,
        icon = icon,
        onClick = { onCheckedChange(!checked) }
    ) {
        Switch(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange)
    }
}
```

You can create a `Repository` with a cold flow coming from `DataStore<Preferences>`. In your view model, use `stateIn` to convert it to a hot flow. You will need to create one function per preference to call `dataStore.edit`, which can be tedious. For simple cases such as `isDarkTheme`, I just provide a datastore `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalDataStore.provides(dataStore))` and call `dataStore.data` directly in my composable functions.

[Full code](https://github.com/bogdan-pechounov/compose-preferences)